# Why can't we pass *,<,> via commandline arguments in C ? Whats happening in background?

Tags: command-line

I know the root cause is how C compiler handles string. But can anyone tell me what exactly these characters are accepted as ? And how can we pass them via commandline(I know adding '\' will make the system accept it, but how can I pass * or < or > as it is ?? I am using gcc compiler; is it a gcc specific issue ?

Comment: Try `myprog ">"`. Similarly if you want space-separated values to be all in the same `argv[]` use quotes again, for example `myprog "1 2 3"`

Comment: @WeatherVane Is there any way it can be passed without '\' or quotes... Thats what I am looking for.

Comment: No there is not, as you have discovered, but the quotes are removed before the argument reaches the program.

Comment: Thanks a bunch . :)

Comment: try using different options that do not get intercepted by the command processor.

Comment: That's not a matter of the C language and definitively not the compiler. If you don't want to follow the shell syntax rules, don't use the shell. If you don't want to follow driving rules don't complain if you get arrested for crashing.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with your C program. The problem is that `*`, `<` and `>` are special characters that the shell processes before they even reach your program. You could shield them from the shell by quoting your input with single quotes (`'`). E.g.:

```
$ ./myprogram arg1 arg2 'arg3<>*'
```

Comment: So I can circumvent this by putting *,<,> in quotes ? Also what if I am trying to accept * as an input from user ? Is there any way I can implement that ??

Comment: If you're getting the input directly from the user (e.g., with `scanf`), you're already in your program - not the shell, so there's no issue there. The point of the quotes is to prevent the shell from interpreting them **before** it passes as argv to your program.

Comment: User is supposed to run this program and pass arguments via commandline. * can be a part of the options passed by the user.